# How to combine multiple sorting functions

Tags: php, sorting

It works like a charm in SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY age DESC, name ASC
```

But what if we have such data in PHP array. How can we do the same? For example, if I have

```php
$a = [
['name' => 'Alfred', 'age' => 40],
['name' => 'Mark', 'age' => 40],
['name' => 'Lue', 'age' => 45],
['name' => 'Ameli', 'age' => 38],
['name' => 'Barb', 'age' => 38],
];
```

and I want to sort it by age in descending order and then by name in ascending order. Just like in the SQL above. So the right sequence of names is: `Lue, Alfred, Mark, Ameli, Barb`.  See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/epMrXQnsSjQVkgTTxvsJ1P/0).

The *wrong* attempt to get it in PHP is:

```php
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return -strnatcasecmp($a['age'], $b['age']); // desc
});

usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return strnatcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']); // asc
});
```

Each of two usort calls works fine, but it overrides the previous result, while I want to combine them all together. Ideally, I'd like to have a function that accepts any amount of Callable to usort them all.

Please advise.

**Update**:
As reasonable commented bellow, [array_multisort](https://www.php.net/array_multisort) is suitable for sorting regular array like this. But I'd like to find solution to combine `comparator closures`. ANY comparators, even like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60156189/272885).
By the way, SQL allows to sort by expression, not only by simple field.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP sort array by two field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4582649/php-sort-array-by-two-field-values)

Comment: @VladimirTarkhanov yes and no. I see how to solve this very case with name and age. But the desired result is to combine any comparator functions, suitable for usort(), not just a field names. I will update my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
function combineComparators(...$comparators)
{
    return function($a, $b) use($comparators)
    {
        foreach($comparators as $c)
        {
            $res = $c($a, $b);
            if($res!=0)
                return $res;
        }
        return 0;
    };
}

$a = [
['name' => 'Alfred', 'age' => 40],
['name' => 'Mark', 'age' => 40],
['name' => 'Lue', 'age' => 45],
['name' => 'Ameli', 'age' => 38],
['name' => 'Barb', 'age' => 38],
];

$cmp1 = function ($a, $b) {
    return -strnatcasecmp($a['age'], $b['age']); // desc
};

$cmp2 = function ($a, $b) {
    return strnatcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']); // asc
};

usort($a, combineComparators($cmp1, $cmp2));

var_dump($a);
```

Comment: @Oliver briliant! It seems working on my example array and functions. I will test it a bit more on other comparators and very likely mark your answer as "solution". 
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/922863c6f7303a36df087730d682f32ae1ecabdd

Answer (score 1):

Somebody will have a good `usort`, but I prefer `array_multisort`.

Extract each column, sort on those in order and then sort the original by that sort order:

```
array_multisort(array_column($a, 'age'), SORT_DESC, array_column($a, 'name'), SORT_ASC, $a);
```

Comment: It's nice but solves only a simple case. I updated my question.